# Quick access to a cell in 2D matrix which wraps around

Tags: c++, math, matrix

I have a matrix which wraps around.

m_matrixOffset points to first cell(0, 0) of the wrapped around matrix. So to access a cell we have below function GetCellInMatrix .Logic to wrap around(in while loop) is executed each time someone access a cell. This is executed thousands of time in a second. Is there any way to optimize this using some lookup or someother way. MAX_ROWS and MAX_COLS may not be power of 2.

```
struct Cell
{
    Int rowId;
    Int colId;
}
int matData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];


int GetCellInMatrix(const Cell& cellIndex)
{
        Cell newCellIndex = cellIndex + m_matrixOffset ;

        while (newCellIndex.rowId > MAX_ROWS)
        {
            newCellIndex.rowId -= MAX_ROWS;
        }

        while (newCellIndex.colId > MX_COLS)
        {
            newCellIndex.y -= MAX_COLS;
        }

    return data[newCellIndex.rowId][newCellIndex.colId];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the concept of division with remainder, usually implemented as `a % b` for the remainder.

Thus

```
return data[newCellIndex.rowId % MAX_ROWS][newCellIndex.colId % MAX_COLS];
```

does not need the `while` loops before it.

---

As per comment, the implied integer division in the remainder computation is too costly if done at each query. Assuming that `m_matrixOffset` is constant over a large number of queries, reduce its coordinates once using the remainder operations. Then the `newCellIndex` are less than twice the maximum, thus need only to be reduced at most once. Thus it is safe to replace `while` with `if`, sparing one comparison.

---

If you can sacrifice memory for space, then double the matrix dimensions and fill the excess entries with the repeated matrix elements. You have to make sure this pattern holds when updating the matrix.

Then, again assuming that both `m_matrixOffset` and `CellIndex` are inside the maxima for rows and columns, you can access the cell of the extended matrix without any further reduction. This would be a variant on the "lookup table" idea.

---

Or use real lookup tables, but you then execute 3 array cell lookups like in

```
return data[repeatedRowIndex[newCellIndex.rowId]][repeatedColIndex[newCellIndex.colId]];
```

Comment: We were doing this earlier, but this is leading to performance issues as this is costly on CPU. Since we access the cells thousands if not millions of times, its not optimal

Comment: Then you need to qualify resp. quantify what the matrix offset is. If you can guarantee that the matrix offset is also smaller than the matrix dimensions (by computing remainders once), you have max. one reduction and can replace `while` with `if`, reducing the effort by one comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the wrap is small or large in relation to the matrix.

The most common case is that all you need is the nearest neighbour. So make the matrix N+2 by M+2 and duplicate the wrap. That makes reads fast but writes a bit fiddly (often  a good trade-off).

If that's no good, specialise the functions. Work out which cells are edge cells and handle the specially (you must be able to do this cheaper than simply hard-coding the logic into the access, of course, if only one or two cells change every pass that will hold, not if you generate a random list every pass).

Comment: Do you mean if have a matrix (512, 512), i need a wrap around matrix (1024, 10234)?

Comment: Often the pattern is that we have a random point on the matrix, and we need all the neighbours. So if we make the matrix 514 x 514 instead of 512 x 512, we don't need special code to read the neighbours. Supporting more distant neighbours become s steadily more expensive.